How do I setup jetbrains Rider to work with mono?
I'm new to programming standalone applications and I want to write a program in c#. I have Rider and recently installed Mono (mono project), added a system variable MONO_PROJECT leading to mono's installation folder and I don't know where to go from here.
In Rider when I go to settings->environment there's only .Net core, xamarin android and xamarin ios & mac.
I'm using windows 10 btw.
In Rider I created a new solution, then added a new class named Main.cs and pasted this code:
namespace EmptyProject1
{
    using System;

    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
        }
    }
}

I had to go to Edit Configurations and add Native Executable and then choose the environment variable mentioned earier. Only then Rider recognised the code I pasted.
Now Rider tells me that both HelloWorld class and Main method are never used.
I tried to build and run but Rider throws me an error saying that my configuration is invalid. I don't know what to choose in the configuration fields. I only filled system variable and working directory (empty folder in documents).
Please help.

Leave Mono alone if you can https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-end-of-mono/

@LexLi what would you recommend instead?

My post already said that. Anything related to .NET Core (8/9 right now) is what you should use.
